# many-to-many database

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization

I'm trying to create a database to analyze the configurations of my servers.
But i have many services that can run on many servers (for failover/load balancing). Also, the configuration of a same service can change from one server to an other, this is why I can't just have a service table

---

I tried to link the different tables using a single table that tie them all together. I think i'm in NF3 but i'm not 100% sure.
Is that a "valide" database design? [database design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEZMD.png)

---

I fear that the request to find stuff in the database are going to be a bit complicated.

thank you

Comment: Looks valid, if it says what you need. Yes, queries can be complicated, but you can build some views to make things easier, or maybe a visual report.

Comment: Potentially opinion based question. And kind of unspecific. Is this homework or something?

Comment: No it's not homework. Federico razzoli answer is enought for me. I wasn't sure I could have a table with only foreign Key to link the others together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help more if you showed the actual db design.  But...
If you have two tables associated in a many to many relationship, you will need a table in between them that represents the relationship.  Tables normally represent entities in the real world, and foreign key represent the relationships.  But in a many to many relationship you need a table to handle that complexity.

That table represents and could be called ServiceRunningOnServer and it's primary key should be the combination of a ServiceId (with a foreign key to Service.Id), and a ServerId (with a foreign key to Server.Id).

Any setting for a service that is across the board (not server specific) is an attribute of the service entity and so belongs in the Service table.  But any setting that **is specific to the server** it is running on, is an attribute of the relationship between that service and that server and so it belongs in the ServiceRunningOnServer table.

Yes, this is a perfectly normalized db design.  And actually it is the design with the most optimized complexity.  Meaning that other designs might make some things easier, but they will also make other things harder.  In the end, and in the total sum of things, other designs will over-complicate things.  This design will keep the total complexity of adding, updating, reading and deleting data from your database to a minimum.